# SSH authentication via GnuPG: The agent has no identities

Tags: ssh, 17.10, gnupg

I used the following [instructions](https://incenp.org/notes/2015/gnupg-for-ssh-authentication.html) to setup a GnuPG authentication key. However, I am having troubles getting it recognized by my SSH agent upon startup.

I put the following lines in my `.profile`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

But on startup:

```
ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Then, if I manually source my `.profile`:

```
ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:<hidden> (none) (RSA)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The following [instructions](https://blog.josefsson.org/2017/06/19/openpgp-smartcard-under-gnome-on-debian-9-0-stretch/) eventually worked for me. Apparently, GNOME keyring has to be explicitly disabled for SSH with:

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
cp /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop ~/.config/autostart
echo 'Hidden=true' >> ~/.config/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
```

And then logging out and in again.